# App crashes sometimes after onClick - Android

Tags: android, crash, onclick

I have a curious problem. My app has a custom Dialog with a button to save a password. It works fine. But sometimes it crashes (I do the same interactions). The Logcat throws a NullPointerException. But I checked the code and did not find a part that causes this error.

The problem is that it is difficult to simulate the error. It occurs just sometimes. What might be a reason? The app hangs sometimes and if I press the button again it crashes.

This is the logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.tapps.guardian.free.MainActivity$7$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:1312)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This seems to be the error code (line 1312ff.):

```
@Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("App", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putString("pass",
                                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password)).getText().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

Comment: Post your logcat and code.

Comment: Post your stackTrace here

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to give you a sensible answer. Post some code and we might be able to help.

Comment: Check my answer it might help...

Comment: Added the logcat. Which code do you need?

Comment: OnClick event code...

Comment: Added the code which causes the error. editor.putString("pass"... is line 1312.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
dialog.cancel();
```

to

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

And find id of

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password))
```

on onCreate() method:

After that get value of EditText in String

```
String str = edt.getText().toString();
```

pass this to SharedPreference

```
editor.putString("pass",str);
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Typically, a dialog is dismissed when its job is finished and it is being removed from the screen. A dialog is canceled when the user wants to escape the dialog and presses the Back button.

For example, you have a standard Yes/No dialog on the screen. If the user clicks No, then the dialog is dismissed and the value for No is returned to the caller. If instead of choosing Yes or No, the user clicks Back to escape the dialog rather than make a choice then the dialog is canceled and no value is returned to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Put a try / catch or if condition there...It mostly happens when you asks user to enter some input and users does not enter the input and Clicks on 'Save Password' button...If you want post that Save password code snippet here and I will help you with the same... Hope this will resolve your problem...

Thanks

Comment: It does not work. I checked it. It works sometimes and crashes sometimes. The input was entered.

Comment: Did u try to handle the exception therE?